# angularjs controller definition

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, angular-ui-router

I have a hello-world app written in angularjs using requirejs to load modules.
The controller-function I set in the $stateProvider (by ui-router) is undefined.
I have uploaded the project on [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/i9Rge9t2CqRvRFDdOUEc?p=catalogue)

```
"Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'HomeCtrl' is not a function, got undefined ...!
```

Do I have to update the scope with sth. like

```
$scope.$apply();
```

Comment: I'm not getting the same error on Plunkr because it can't find the scripts. It's probably because `HomeCtrl` is undefined because the ` app.controller` method isn't run for some reason.

Comment: Do you know how I can make the app.controller method run?
I just uploaded the files. It's dependencies are not correct. Sry